# How to subtract these two dates in Django/python?

Tags: python, django, datetime, datetime-format

I get start_date like this: `start_date1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)`

and pass end_date as a function argument like this:

```
a(datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
```

They both are stored in database under `start_date and end_date` coloum name.

What I am trying to do is subtract end_date and start_date to get duration:

```
  start_date = [i.start_date for i in b ]
  end_date = [i.end_date for i in b ]
```

I would use this to subtract those two dates: `t = [i - j for i, j in zip(y, x)]`

However the problem is start_date and end_date are returned in unicodes. I can't convert them into datetime format again. What should I do?

Comment: If you want to show the difference at templates, you can use `timesince` tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince

Comment: Python has extensive, timezone-aware [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) features which are well-documented.

Answer (score 0):

The result of substracting one datetime object from another in python is a `timedelta` object. A `datetime` object is defined as a period of time from epoch (00:00:00 on 1 Jan 1970). Subtracting one `datetime` from another cannot return a new `datetime` object (since it can't be relative to Epoch), what you'll get back is just period of time. That's a `timedelta`.

There's lots of detail in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Comment: I know that. But the start_date and end_date are returned in unicode from databases which can't be subtracted.

Comment: Then you need to convert back to datetime objects before you do your calculation. You'll want to use the strptime function - http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime